# CVXPY Problem with DCP rules at param*norm

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I recently discovered the cvxpy package and try to use it on a pretty basic minimization problem.
But while initializing my convex problem I always get a DCP Error which i can't explain.

```python
x = Variable(m)
gamma = Parameter(value=1.0)

cost = sum_squares(np.transpose(A_shaped)*x - b_real) + gamma*norm(x,1)
obj = Minimize(cost)
constr = [np.transpose(A_shaped)* x <= b_real + abs(b_real * eps),
          np.transpose(A_shaped)* x >= b_real - abs(b_real * eps)]

prob = Problem(obj, constr)
print(prob.is_dcp())
```

All the parameters like *m*, *A_shaped*, *b_real* and *eps* are defined before.

**My Problem:** 
Whenever I use the Parameter *gamma* in the declaration of *cost* and I want to solve it cvxpy tells me the problem does not follow DCP rules and it's because of the subexpression *param123* * *norm124*. 
When I replace *gamma* by 1.0 or remove it I don't get this error and *prob.is_dcp()* returns *True*, which I can't explain, because I initialize *gamma* with the value 1.0.

If you need further information feel free to ask and thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the solution:
I only tested to set the parameter's argument *nonpos* to *False* but that didn't help. What I didn't know, there's also the argument *nonneg*, which I then set to *True* and now the DCP analysis returns *True* as well.